H-Bridge with inductive load default state
I am developing a circuit for controlling solenoid valves and i am using H-Bridges (composed of PMOS and NMOS transistors). My question is whether it is important, when the H-Bridge is in its default state, to have the bottom NMOS transistors on (thus grounding the solenoid valve pins) or to keep them off, resulting in two Hi-Z nodes at the H-Bridge outputs.
I am aware that Hi-Z nodes can be more prone to picking up noise, but I am unsure if this is of any importance, particularly at low voltages (<12V).

The choice could affect how quickly the solenoid current decays on turn off.  Also, when you refer to the FETs being open or closed it can be confusing since an open circuit does not conduct current.  It's better to refer to them being on or off.

Is there a good reason to use H-bridges to control a solenoid?

@Andyaka yes, the valve is latching so i need to control the current direction

A high-impedance state is likely of little consequence for an output.  If you must, a pull-down resistor could set the default state of one or both terminals; indeed this is sometimes done on purpose, to put a little bias current through the load, and thus sense if it has gone open-circuit (for loads that don't mind leakage: lamps, solenoids, etc.).
Also, the voltage range is bounded (by the MOSFET body diodes, and supply bypass capacitor(s) at least, if not also a TVS or etc.), so it might be open circuit, but it's not oooopen open.  Sometimes, a broadly constrained range is as good as a narrow (e.g. shorted) one.
You might also be concerned about the converse, emitting noise: if the outputs are kept shorted, there is a direct path to circuit ground, which might be noisy.  While it's better to avoid emitting noise in the first place, it might still be that a locally noisy driver isn't avoidable without significantly more work, and so leaving them open circuit, or better still, biasing the outputs to mid-supply to reduce Coss, and thus increase the AC impedance to the cable.
It could also be a cross-wiring hazard, if that should be a concern: suppose one line gets shorted to supply on accident.  Then it would only draw fault currents when activated, perhaps a much less likely event than if it were always-on.
This assumes you're already handling the solenoid properly, in and of itself; discharging by driven inverse pulse, for example.  Or by open-circuiting the bridge momentarily (to let it self-discharge), then shorting afterwards.  Leaving it shorted during turn-off forces discharge to occur only through coil resistance, which may take longer than desired.

Once your Solenoid is latched, it is an inductor.  I have drawn a circuit showing the H-bridge with P- and N-channel MOSFETS and showing their body diodes.
When the solenoid is powered, the current path is shown with the red arrows.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When you power down the solenoid, the solenoid coil is discharged through the body diodes of the other MOSFETs:

simulate this circuit
So you must choose MOSFETs whose internal diodes are capable of handling your solenoid current, or install external diodes to "catch" the solenoid current.
Regardless of leaving the lower MOSFET on or off  these diodes will prevent the solenoid coil from floating above the power supply or below ground by more than one diode drop.  If you have a high impedance power source or series inductance on your power line or ground line running to your solenoid, you can expect a spike when you power off.  Putting a large capacitance on the power line next to the solenoid coil can help reduce this.
